# Mobile Overlay menu does not close when anchor links are clicked

Tags: javascript, html, menu, overlay

My mobile menu closes when a regular link is clicked (eg: https://link.com), but when an anchor link is clicked (#anchor), the anchor scrolls to the correct position on the page, but does not close the menu. How can I make sure the overlay menu is removed when an anchor is clicked like it disappears when a regular link is clicked?

Any help appreciated.

HTML...

```
<div class="open-nav-menu">
<span></span>
</div>
<div class="menu-overlay">
</div>
<nav class="nav-menu">
  <div class="close-nav-menu">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
  </div>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#join">Join</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

JS Code...

```
(() => {
    const openNavMenu = document.querySelector(".open-nav-menu"),
        closeNavMenu = document.querySelector(".close-nav-menu"),
        navMenu = document.querySelector(".nav-menu"),
        menuOverlay = document.querySelector(".menu-overlay"),
        mediaSize = 991;
    openNavMenu.addEventListener("click", toggleNav);
    closeNavMenu.addEventListener("click", toggleNav);
    // close the navMenu by clicking outside
    menuOverlay.addEventListener("click", toggleNav);


    function toggleNav() {
        navMenu.classList.toggle("open");
        menuOverlay.classList.toggle("active");
        document.body.classList.toggle("hidden-scrolling");
    }
    navMenu.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        if (event.target.hasAttribute("data-toggle") && window.innerWidth <= mediaSize) {
            // prevent default anchor click behavior
            event.preventDefault();
            const menuItemHasChildren = event.target.parentElement;
            // if menuItemHasChildren is already expanded, collapse it
            if (menuItemHasChildren.classList.contains("active")) {
                collapseSubMenu();
            } else {
                // collapse existing expanded menuItemHasChildren
                if (navMenu.querySelector(".menu-item-has-children.active")) {
                    collapseSubMenu();
                }
                // expand new menuItemHasChildren
                menuItemHasChildren.classList.add("active");
                const subMenu = menuItemHasChildren.querySelector(".sub-menu");
                subMenu.style.maxHeight = subMenu.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        }
    });

    function collapseSubMenu() {
        navMenu.querySelector(".menu-item-has-children.active .sub-menu").removeAttribute("style");
        navMenu.querySelector(".menu-item-has-children.active").classList.remove("active");
    }

    function resizeFix() {
        // if navMenu is open ,close it
        if (navMenu.classList.contains("open")) {
            toggleNav();
        }
        // if menuItemHasChildren is expanded , collapse it
        if (navMenu.querySelector(".menu-item-has-children.active")) {
            collapseSubMenu();
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
        if (this.innerWidth > mediaSize) {
            resizeFix();
        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this code to check if any links were being clicked, then removed the overlay class....

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul.menu li').forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('nav').classList.remove('open');
}));
```